# Overriding Python import without causing restricted execution mode

Tags: python

I need to override the default importer within a lambda function (compile()) so that I can use alternate versions of some modules. However, the lambda code need not be running with "restricted execution" (RE) since only authorized people will be producing the code that is being compiled. We also require being able to open files, which is prevented in RE:

```
IOError: file() constructor not accessible in restricted mode
```

However, in order to override the importer, I need to copy the __builtin __ module and assign a new importer to __import __. However, using the alternate version of __builtin __ is specifically what causes RE.

How can I simply override the importer without causing the RE side-effect?

EDIT: For those that haven't experienced this and don't have the imagination:

```
def copy_module(m):
    x = type(m)(m.__name__, m.__doc__)
    x.__dict__.update(m.__dict__)
    return x

# Make sure we get the module in all situations (depending on where 
# __builtins__ is invoked, it may be a dictionary).
builtins = __import__('__builtin__')

custom_builtins = copy_module(builtins)
custom_builtins.__import__ = __import__

l = """\
with open('/dev/null') as f:
    pass
"""

c = compile(l, 'open_test', 'exec')

globals_ = {
    '__builtins__': custom_builtins, 
    '__name__': '__handler__', 
    '__doc__': None, 
    '__package__': None,
}

locals_ = {}

exec c in globals_, locals_
```

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import_replace_2.py", line 31, in <module>
    exec c in globals_, locals_
  File "open_test", line 1, in <module>
IOError: file() constructor not accessible in restricted mode
```

Answer (score -2):

I did not get the RE error. From the python docs:

> **__import__**: This function is invoked by the import statement. It can be replaced (by importing the __builtin__ module and assigning to __builtin__.__import__) in order to change semantics of the import statement

The following works for me (it does everything the same as the standard import, but replace spam with math.

```
>>> import builtins
>>> _import_alias = __import__
>>> builtins.__import__ = lambda module, *args, **kwargs: _import_alias(module.replace("spam", "math"), *args, **kwargs)
>>> import spam as math
>>> math.factorial(10)
```

It is important that you create an alias of `__import__` and that you override `builtins.__import__`,  not the standard `__import__`.

Comment: You're not listening. This has to be a *copy* of __import __, and you have to attempt an file/open operation. You need to know what you're talking about in order to respond.